# How to capture old checkbox value and set it back on cancel the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, checkbox

I have checkbox and option to check/uncheck using an Edit option and Cancel option.Issue is that when I uncheck a previously checked value or vise versa and hit cancel event the checkbox does not retain its original value(checked) and shows unchecked. I want that on click of cancel, the checkbox should show original value. here is my javascript code:

```
 function Cancel(Login, ID, IsBlock) {
        debugger;
        $("#chk" + ID).val(IsBlock);
        $("#chk" + ID).prop("disabled", true);
        document.getElementById("Edit " + ID).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Update " + ID).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Cancel " + ID).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

and here is my html

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0);" id='Edit @Model[i].ID' onclick="Edit(@Model[i].ID)">Edit</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id='Update @Model[i].ID'   onclick="Update('@Model[i].Login','@Model[i].ID')" style="display:none">
                            Update</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" id='Cancel @Model[i].ID'   onclick="Cancel('@Model[i].Login','@Model[i].ID','@Model[i].IsBlock')" style="display:none">
                                Cancel</a>
```

Comment: We need more code then this to help you, maybe you can create JSBin, Codepen with your full code.

Answer (score 0):

One way of storing the `old state` of a `checkbox` is to declare a `global variable` (a variable that is declared outside all functions) and to store the `old state` there.

You will need:

- a `onchange event listener function` for the `checkbox` in which you will simply set the `old state` of the `checkbox` to the `opposite` of the `new state`.
- a `cancel function` to `revert` the `changes` in which you would check if the `old state` and `current state` match, and if they do then `do nothing`, otherwise `revert changes`.
- a `global variable` to store the `old state` of the `checkbox` in order to `compare` with the `current state`.

**The code:** (run the snippet at the bottom)

(includes your function, a global variable, and two functions for demostration)

```js
// oldState is now a global variable
var oldState = true;  // lets say the initial state of the checkbox was checked


// this is your function, modified
function Cancel(Login, ID, IsBlock)
{
        debugger;
        $("#chk" + ID).val(IsBlock);
        var isChecked = $("#chk" + ID).prop('checked');

        // the old and current value are the same, do nothing
        if((isChecked && oldState) || (!isChecked && !oldState)) {} 
        else
        {
            // the old and current value are NOT the same, revert changes
            if(isChecked) $("#chk" + ID).prop('checked', false);
            else $("#chk" + ID).prop('checked', true);
        }
        
        document.getElementById("Edit " + ID).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Update " + ID).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Cancel " + ID).style.display = 'none';
}


// listen for checkbox change event
$('#c').change(function()
{
  // set the old state to the opposite of the current
  if(this.checked) oldState = false;
  else oldState = true;
});


// this is an example function to demonstrate reverting
function revert()
{
    // make a variable to shorten the code
    var isChecked = $("#c").prop('checked');
    // the old and current value are the same, do nothing
    if((isChecked && oldState) || (!isChecked && !oldState)) {} 
    else
    {
        // the old and current value are NOT the same, revert changes
        if(isChecked) $("#c").prop('checked', false);
        else $("#c").prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a  href="javascript:void(0);" id='Edit @Model[i].ID' onclick="Edit(@Model[i].ID)">Edit</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='Update @Model[i].ID'   onclick="Update('@Model[i].Login','@Model[i].ID')" style="display:none">Update</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='Cancel @Model[i].ID' onclick="Cancel('@Model[i].Login','@Model[i].ID','@Model[i].IsBlock')" style="display:none">Cancel</a>

<!-- Demonstration -->
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" checked="checked" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Click Me To Change" onclick="revert()" />
```